# Alternative to dart-protoc-plugin for Windows

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers

I want to implement dart-protobuf, but the dart-protoc-plugin (project to generate your Dart protobuf library from a proto definition) does not currently support Windows.  I can not find an alternative to the plugin. Is there no other way to generate the definitions for Dart? Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Until some weeks ago "doesn't supported" didn't mean that it don't work on Windows, but now it is broken =( I think the best way is to use a simple linux vm as mentioned by Günter. Maybe we should comment on https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-protoc-plugin/issues/10 to show our interest in a Windows version.

Comment: Thanks, I left comment on your issue#25

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no other.
I think the easiest way would be to set up a Linux VM to run it.
I'm sure it would be easier to make it run on Windows than building a new one.

Comment: Thanks! Setting up a Linux VM would also work, but I finally got a pure Windows solution working using Fox32's batch file suggestions.