# Dart protobuf: what version of protoc should I download?

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am attempting to follow instructions in this article:

https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/serialization#protobuf-example

Step one is to install protocol compiler. My question is, does it matter which version I download? Do I need to use the javasript version as Dart will be compiling down to Javascript? Please see below link to list of all protoc downloads to see what I mean:

https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0

Any advise would be massively appreciated. Apologies if this has a very obvious answer - I am quite new to this and struggling to find more information anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything special for JS. The compiler generates Dart code that gets compiled to JS

Install one of:

- `protoc-3.0.0-linux-x86_32.zip`
- `protoc-3.0.0-linux-x86_64.zip`
- `protoc-3.0.0-osx-x86_32.zip`
- `protoc-3.0.0-osx-x86_64.zip`
- `protoc-3.0.0-win32.zip`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - exactly what I wanted to know!

Just one other thing, I have 64-bit windows but there is only win32 avaliable to download. Do you know is that a problem for me or should the win32 download you reference run fine on 64 bit?

Comment: Win32 runs fine on Win64. Just the RAM is limited to 3 Gig ;-) for this app

Comment: Ah, turns out this is not working on windows anyway. See you recommended setting up a VM here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671896/alternative-to-dart-protoc-plugin-for-windows/22672801#22672801

I guess this is still the case as unable to make the plugin on windows machine.

Comment: Right, forgot that there were issues on Windows. Wasn't aware this is still an issue.